# Static files status' 404

Tags: django, heroku

I'm using **heroku** to host my Django(1.6) app (called '**Zen**'). The problem is static files aren't showing. In other words, there's no CSS and no JS in my app because it doesn't found those files. I looked to other questions here and I configured my app as below:

**Settings.py**:

```
##### Static asset configuration #####
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from zen import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

**wsgi.py**:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "zen.settings")
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Apparently, after pushing my app with `git push heroku master` all is working great:

`-----> Preparing static assets
       Running collectstatic...
       69 static files copied to '/app/staticfiles'.`

But as you can see there is no CSS in my app (http://obscure-reef-8874.herokuapp.com/). I looked to my app's log and mostly css and js files are in 404 status... I tried everything, can you help me?

EDIT:

I didn't find the bug, I recreated an app and it worked, simple.

Comment: try `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'staticfiles')`

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
```

try 
May be caused by different STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your static file serving: that is fine, as you can see if you go to the admin application: http://obscure-reef-8874.herokuapp.com/admin/. Files under /static/admin/ are being served with no problem.

Without seeing the structure of your application and the way you are outputting the static links in your template it's hard to help, I guess that your files are inside a subdirectory of /static/, so you'll need to reference that subdirectory in the links to the assets in your template.

Note that you should remove the additional static URL patterns from your urls.py. They do not work when DEBUG is False. Your files are served by Cling, which is external to Django.